# PyODBC SQL type error when reading query in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, odbc, pyodbc

Looking for some help with a specific error when I write out from a `pyodbc` connection. How do I fix the error:

> ODBC SQL type -360 is not yet supported. column-index=1 type=-360', 'HY106' error from PYODBC

Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import sqlparse

## Function created to read SQL Query
def create_query_string(sql_full_path):
    with open(sql_full_path, 'r') as f_in:
        lines = f_in.read()

    # remove any common leading whitespace from every line
    query_string = textwrap.dedent("""{}""".format(lines))
    ## remove comments from SQL Code
    query_string = sqlparse.format(query_string, strip_comments=True)

    return query_string

query_string = create_query_string("Bad Code from R.sql")

## initializes the connection string
curs = conn.cursor()

df=pd.read_sql(query_string,conn)

df.to_csv("TestSql.csv",index=None)
```

We are using the following SQL code in query string:

```sql
SELECT loss_yr_qtr_cd, 
       CASE 
         WHEN loss_qtr_cd <= 2 THEN loss_yr_num 
         ELSE loss_yr_num + 1 
       END                    AS LOSS_YR_ENDING, 
       snap_yr_qtr_cd, 
       CASE 
         WHEN snap_qtr_cd <= 2 THEN snap_yr_num 
         ELSE snap_yr_num + 1 
       END                    AS CAL_YR_ENDING, 
       cur_ctstrph_loss_ind, 
       clm_symb_grp_cd, 
       adbfdb_pol_form_nm, 
       risk_st_nm, 
       wrt_co_nm, 
       wrt_co_part_cd, 
       src_of_bus_cd, 
       rt_zip_dlv_ofc_cd, 
       cur_rst_rt_terr_cd, 
       Sum(xtra_cntrc_py_amt) AS XTRA_CNTRC_PY_AMT 
FROM   (SELECT DT.loss_yr_qtr_cd, 
               DT.loss_qtr_cd, 
               DT.loss_yr_num, 
               SNAP.snap_yr_qtr_cd, 
               SNAP.snap_qtr_cd, 
               SNAP.snap_yr_num, 
               CLM.cur_ctstrph_loss_ind, 
               CLM.clm_symb_grp_cd, 
               POL_SLCT.adbfdb_pol_form_nm, 
               POL_SLCT.adbfdb_pol_form_cd, 
               CVR.bsic_cvr_ind, 
               POL_SLCT.priv_pass_ind, 
               POL_SLCT.risk_st_nm, 
               POL_SLCT.wrt_co_nm, 
               POL_SLCT.wrt_co_part_cd, 
               POL_SLCT.src_of_bus_cd, 
               TERR.rt_zip_dlv_ofc_cd, 
               TERR.cur_rst_rt_terr_cd, 
               LOSS.xtra_cntrc_py_amt 
        FROM   ahshdm1d.vmaloss_day_dt_dim DT, 
               ahshdm1d.vmasnap_yr_mo_dim SNAP, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaaclm_dim CLM, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaapol_slct_dim POL_SLCT, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaacvr_dim CVR, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaart_terr_dim TERR, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaaloss_fct LOSS, 
               ahshdm1d.tmaaprod_bus_dim BUS 
        WHERE  SNAP.snap_yr_qtr_cd BETWEEN '20083' AND '20182' 
               AND TRIM(POL_SLCT.adbfdb_lob_cd) = 'A' 
               AND CVR.bsic_cvr_ind = 'Y' 
               AND POL_SLCT.priv_pass_ind = 'Y' 
               AND POL_SLCT.adbfdb_pol_form_cd = 'V' 
               AND POL_SLCT.src_of_bus_cd NOT IN ( 'ITC', 'INV' ) 
               AND LOSS.xtra_cntrc_py_amt > 0 
               AND LOSS.loss_day_dt_id = DT.loss_day_dt_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.cvr_dim_id = CVR.cvr_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.pol_slct_dim_id = POL_SLCT.pol_slct_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.rt_terr_dim_id = TERR.rt_terr_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.prod_bus_dim_id = BUS.prod_bus_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.clm_dim_id = CLM.clm_dim_id 
               AND LOSS.snap_yr_mo_dt_id = SNAP.snap_yr_mo_dt_id) AS TABLE1 
GROUP  BY loss_yr_qtr_cd, 
          loss_qtr_cd, 
          loss_yr_num, 
          snap_yr_qtr_cd, 
          snap_qtr_cd, 
          snap_yr_num, 
          cur_ctstrph_loss_ind, 
          clm_symb_grp_cd, 
          adbfdb_pol_form_nm, 
          risk_st_nm, 
          wrt_co_nm, 
          wrt_co_part_cd, 
          src_of_bus_cd, 
          rt_zip_dlv_ofc_cd, 
          cur_rst_rt_terr_cd 
FOR FETCH only
```

Just looking how to properly write out the database.

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Are you certain query string looks like that after your `create_query_string` call? This appears to be DB2 syntax. Please tag your RDBMS. Also, we need to see the data types of all fields. Likely pyodbc does not support for a specific field(s).

Comment: @Parfait, Yes I am.  When I take out the nested portion, it works fine.  I am trying to replicate the exact script I have in R.  RODBC seems to handle the process fine, and I was trying to figure out why I can't seem to get it to work exactly in Python.

Comment: That is very interesting as this is an ODBC error and not Python error and likely you use same driver in both R and Python ODBC connections. Are you reading the query from file also in R? Please pastebin or Github gist that R code you claim is *exact script* like this.

Comment: Also, what is `textwrap`? What is `conn`? Please make sure your code is fully compilable with all objects assigned. Check encoding of your script as there may be a character(s) causing issues. You can edit your post (see link below question).

Comment: Hi Parfait, thanks for looking into this.  It ended up being the SQL code was the result of the issue.  In the two case statements, Python was reading in the results with varying types, causing a DECFLOAT error.  Thanks again.